# Ошибка - Failed to complete gradle execution

Tags: android-studio, java

Я осваиваю Android studio.

Давеча целый день программировал и тестировал на своем устройстве всякие helloworld'ы. Сегодня после первого же тестового запуска получил ошибку:

> Failed to complete Gradle execution.
>
> Cause: Unable to start the daemon
> process. This problem might be caused
> by incorrect configuration of the
> daemon. For example, an unrecognized
> jvm option is used. Please refer to
> the user guide chapter on the daemon
> at
> http://gradle.org/docs/2.2.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
> Please read the following process
> output to find out more:
> ----------------------- Error occurred during initialization of VM Could not
> reserve enough space for 1048576KB
> object heap Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
> warning: ignoring option
> MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed
> in 8.0

Гугл ничего не дал. Знает кто-нибудь, как решить проблему?

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, ему недостаточно памяти, попробуйте в настройках File-->Setting-->Gradle-- в окне Gradle Vm Option добавить -Xmx256m.